# Revenge voting and close votes

Tags: support, vote-to-close, down-votes

Obviously I've made someone mad.  I'm not too concerned about that; however, it did bring up a question in my mind.

When someone mass down votes a person I know that there are systems in place to catch and "fix" that.  However, what about mass close votes?

Whoever it is that decided they don't like me not only down voted but also voted to close the same 4 questions they downvoted.

Does the Rep recalc take into account close votes left by the perpetrator or are those ignored?

Comment: If the questions are fine, they shouldn't get the 4 other necessary close votes to get the question closed, and the close-vote expires.

Comment: there shouldn't be any hit to your rep from a close vote - if anyone else comes across it in the review queue they should vote to leave open, and no damage done...

Comment: @3ventic: Understood.  But really such activity just adds to the noise of SO's already overburdened close review queue.  Also, I'm not worried about any rep damage... it would take a LOT - as in probably 10k or so to bother me.  It just seems that the system ought to take other actions into account beyond the vote if it doesn't already.

Comment: @ChrisLively one would assume expired votes leave the queue, but I wouldn't know coming from a smaller site

Comment: Mass closevotings should be  reported to a moderator.

Comment: Looking over the close votes, they don't appear frivolous, actually. [This question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/322440/api-to-determine-cell-carrier) is indeed a request for an external resource and probably *should* be closed as Off Topic.

Comment: I'm not saying a mass CV spree against a user is to be condoned, but all OT votes that I see are defensible.

Comment: @MartijnPieters: Interesting.  The API question is really old however considering SO's current policy, I agree that it should be closed.  Heck, I'll vote to close it myself. ;)

Answer (score 2):

It takes 5 votes to close, and most reviewers check the posts before voting. There are some who don't, but not so much in the close vote queue.

A couple of bad close votes is nothing to be worried about. If the post does get closed, you can always ask for reopening.

However, you should consider the possibility that the post is in fact in need of improvement.

Comment: The questions that were hit are all 4 and 5 years old, with thousands of views, favorited, etc... and no, I didn't downvote you. :)  lovely.